# Is there a way to live catch any sms that come to my android phone from a certain number and send it to my node js app to use it in programing?

Tags: android, node.js, api, express, apk

I saw an apk that catch any sms on android that come from certian number and send it to node js api and use that message in app programing, anyone know if there is a npm or article that explain how to do that ?

I tried to use programs that catch from android but can't extract the sms text from the programs to use it in my nodejs app